# Why are the big frameworks ignoring precondition checks?

Tags: php, zend-framework, codeigniter

From what I know, checking preconditions is a good practice. If a method needs an int value then it's a good solution to do use something like this:

```
public function sum($input1, $input2) {
if (!is_int($input1)) throw new Exception('Input must be a integer');
```

However after looking to the source code of Zend/Codeigniter I don't see checks like this very often. Is there a reason for this ?

Comment: No real idea, but it could be an efficiency thing.

Comment: I don't agree that the cores of the frameworks you mentioned lack preconditions.  When I look through the CodeIgniter core, I see tons of them.

Where are you not seeing preconditions where you believe they should be?  That would probably lead to a better discussion here.

Comment: dynamic language, duck typing, optimization. this sort of thing just doesn't really manifest as a problem, and seems like more of an over complication in most situations.

Comment: in what specific method in one of these frameworks do you think that this may become a problem?

Comment: @calvin - numer_helper.php, function byte_format($num, $precision = 1), num and precision is not checked, if a string ends up there a nice fat Warning is generated

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say that's a general rule, I'd say they do checks but sometimes they miss, and that's why new releases are there for. If you find there's something not right let them know and suggest a patch, I'm sure thousands of people will be grateful to you. And, besisdes, as @soandos suggested, there could be a reason for that

Comment: Not particularly talking about specific function, but I think generally internal functions shouldn't have validations as long as they don't interact with users or security related (database,shell).  developers should understand what input they should send. if the function deals with user input then it should have validation.   IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is difficult / inefficient to test each and every variable before you use it. Instead they check just input variables - check visitors at the door, not once inside the house.

It is of course a good defensive programming technique to test at least more important vars before using them, especially if the input comes from many places.

This is a bit off-topic, but the solution I would recommend is to test input variables like this:

```
$username=get('username', 'string');
$a=get('a', 'int');
...
```

$_REQUEST and similar should never be used (or even be accessible) directly.

Also, when doing HTML output, you should always use this:

```
echo html($username); // replaces '<' with '&lt;' - uses htmlentities
```

To avoid SQL injection attacks one can use MeekroDB, but it is unfortunately very limiting (MySQL only, single DB only,...). It has a good API though which promotes safety, so I would recommend checking it out. 
For myself I have build a small DB library that is based on PDO and uses prepared statements. YMMV.

Comment: This is priceless:  check visitors at the door, not once inside the house.

Comment: It all boils down to basic type theory. You want to insert something into your HTML output? You don't need a String, you need an HTMLString. HTMLString would be a type of String, but your user doesn't ever give you an HTMLString, your user gives you a String. You need to convert that String to the expected type before outputting it. I know of only ONE project which actually follows this pattern. Many others pay lipservice to the idea, but basically get it backwards (eg: allowing one to mark a variable as "untrusted" - This was never about Trust! It's about Types!).

Answer (score 2):

Specifying such strict preconditions in any case is not necessary and feels not useful in a dynamical typed language.

```
$sum = sum("1", "2");
```

Why one should forbid it? Additional if you throw an Exception, one tries to avoid it. This means, he will test and cast himself

```
function sum ($a, $b) {
  if (!is_int($a)) throw new Exception('Input must be a integer');
  if (!is_int($b)) throw new Exception('Input must be a integer');
  return $a + $b;
}

if (!is_int($value1)) { $value1 = (int) $value1; }
if (!is_int($value2)) { $value2 = (int) $value2; }
$sum = sum($value1, $value2);
```

Every `is_int()` occurs multiple times just to avoid unnecessary Exceptions.

Its sufficient to validate values, when you receive them, not all over the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about ZF, i'd say that they try to minimize it in favour of interfaces and classes. You can see in many definitions across ZF something like this:

```
public function preDispatch(Zend_Request_Http $request)
```

which is fine enough. Also at critical places where ints/strings are needed there are some sanity checks. But mostly not in the form of `is_string()` but rather as `isValidLocale()` that calls some other class to check validity.